# Attachment doesn't filled in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form, cocoon-gem

Rails 4.2.1, Ruby 2.2.1 and PostgreSQL 9.3

I have `region` and `pattern` models

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patterns, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patterns, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Pattern < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_attached_file :picture
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, content_type: "image/png"
end
```

And nested form in slim format with `cocoon` gem

```
= simple_form_for(@region) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :patterns do |pattern|
    = render 'pattern_fields', f: pattern
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add pattern', f, :patterns
```

`_pattern_fields.html.slim` view

```
.nested-fields
  .form-inline
    = f.input :picture, as: :file
    = link_to_remove_association f, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' do
      .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
```

I can easily create region with multiple patterns, but when I click edit, file fields are empty.

[image]

Is there nice way to properly work with file fields and rails forms with paperclip?

Comment: Did you check your database if the images are being stored and associated with the region/pattern while creating it?

Comment: @Deep yes. In schema.rb patterns table has `region_id` column